# json parse not correctly generate array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I try to parse the following string which i get via an http endpoint into an array `JSON.parse`:

```
const jsonstring = "{ id: 'Nmq85HbJNnBMFCbCZ', users: [ "A1", "A2", "A3" ] }"
const json = JSON.parse(jsonstring); // outputs: { id: 'Nmq85HbJNnBMFCbCZ', users: [ 'A1', 'A2', 'A3' ] }
```

But when i access the array, there is:

```
for( const element in json.users ) console.log('Element:', element); // Element is 0, 1, 2... instead of A1, A2, A3
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: By your output, it sounds like you're doing `for( const element in json.users)`, are you definitely using `for(const element in json)` ?

Comment: Ah yes. I am going to correct it.

Comment: You can use a `for..of` loop to loop over an array's elements. A `for..in` loop will loop over the properties of the array (such as its indexes), see the link at the top of your question for more details

Comment: Correct. That was the problem.